# Using preg_replace to filter custom textarea

Tags: custom-post-types, actions, post-meta

I am developing a `custom post type`, which, among others includes the possibility of sending an email from within the post editor. The email body textarea is populated through a custom settings page and saved into a `post_meta array` which also includes the email and subject. Until here all fine.

The standard email content from the settings page includes `%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%` and `%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%` which are supposed to be filtered out and replaced with a html link and a normal link to the permalink of the post where the email has originated from.

The following is the function as i have it right now:

```
function filter_email_text_for_post_link( $post ) {

// retrieve the 'proposal_email' post_meta (array)
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proposal_email', TRUE );
// retrieve email body 'proposal_email_text' from array
$email_content = $post_meta['proposal_email_text'];

// bail if email has no content
if( $email_content == '' ){ return; }

// patterns to look for in email body
$link_pattern = '%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%';
$url_pattern  = '%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%';

// returns for each pattern
$proposal_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '">here</a>';
$porposal_link_url = get_permalink( $post_id );

// match and replace with the above patterns
$email_content = str_replace( $link_pattern, $proposal_link, $email_content );
$email_content = str_replace( $url_pattern, $proposal_link_url, $email_content );

// update the post_meta
$post_meta['proposal_email_text'] = $email_content;
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proposal_email', $post_meta );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'filter_email_text_for_post_link' );
```

for some reason, this just isn't working; at all, no errors, no nothing! Initially i tried invoking this function (slightly edited) in the function which saves the data on save_post but that wasn't working either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final, working function:

In comparison to my initial function ended up using `str_replace` in stead of `preg_replace` as the resulting code was shorter more concise and faster. Also added two arguments to the `add_action` call removing the need to use `Global $post`; furthermore removed notices in case where `$post_meta['proposal_email_text']` has not been set (new post).

```
function filter_email_text_for_post_link( $post_id, $post ) {

// retrieve the 'proposal_email' post_meta (array)
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proposal_email', TRUE );
// retrieve email body 'proposal_email_text' from array
if( ! empty( $post_meta['proposal_email_text'] ) ){
    $email_content = $post_meta['proposal_email_text'];
} else {
    return; 
}

// bail if email has no content
if( $email_content == '' ){ return; }

// patterns to look for in email body
$link_pattern = '%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%';
$url_pattern  = '%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%';

// returns for each pattern
$proposal_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '">here</a>';
$proposal_link_url = get_permalink( $post_id );

// match and replace with the above patterns
$email_content = str_replace( $link_pattern, $proposal_link, $email_content );
$email_content = str_replace( $url_pattern, $proposal_link_url, $email_content );

// update the post_meta
$post_meta['proposal_email_text'] = $email_content;
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proposal_email', $post_meta );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'filter_email_text_for_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Add an explanation about what was wrong to this answer, and how you fixed it. Then accept it. Helps the next person who comes along.

Comment: Also, you don't need a global. Tell `add_action` to pass two arguments and the second will be the `$post` object.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace` expects it's regex to be surrounded by a character. Usually that's a slash, like this:

```
'/.*/'
```

When you do this:

```
preg_replace('%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%', $some_text, $replacement);
```

`preg_replace` thinks the first two `%` are your surrounding characters, and fails because of an unrecognized modifier. This is easy to test:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo preg_replace('%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%', '%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%', 'here'), PHP_EOL;
PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'P' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. preg_replace() php shell code:1

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'P' in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
   28.9460     235264   1. {main}() php shell code:0
   28.9460     236016   2. preg_replace() php shell code:1


php >
```

You have two options:

Change your patterns to something like this: `/%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%/` and `/%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%/`

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo preg_replace('/%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%/', '%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%', 'here'), PHP_EOL;
here
```

Forget all about `preg_replace` because you don't need it. Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) instead.

```
<?php
str_replace('%%PROPOSAL_LINK_URL%%', $proposal_link_url, $email_content);
str_ireplace('%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%', $proposal_link, $email_content);
```

Be aware that `str_replace` and it's brethren are not safe for use on strings that contain multi-byte characters (eg. UTF-8) by default. You can [change this](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).

*NOTE: you've used `$link_pattern` twice in your code examples. I think you mean the second one to be `$url_pattern`.*

**EDIT:** it appears there's not a `mb_*` replacement for `str_replace` or `str_ireplace` [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#109937) on php.net sheds some light on the issue. `str_replace` *should* work on multibyte strings, providing the encoding of the needle and haystack are the same.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error in the code, also i wasn't aware that str_replace wasn't safe tu use with UTF-8 so much appreciated.

Comment: Which is the overloading function for `str_replace`?

Comment: oooo, good catch. I don't think there is one.

Comment: unofficialy `mb_str_replace` apparently but according to some comments on [link]http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php `str_replace` works just fine in a multi-byte strings; there are several functions on that site if anyone is having any problems though. I haven't tested any of them though.

Comment: @Ronnieinspain `mb_str_replace` does not exists as `mbstring` function. And `str_replace` works perfectly with utf-8 strings see [here](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8#str_replace).

Comment: Thanks @g.m.. Btw, how do i mark a post as resolved on here? can't find the option to do so.

Comment: @Ronnieinspain on top lef of the answer, under the number of votes and the arrows to upvote/downvote there is a grey check sign. Click on it. Your own solution can be marked as the accepted one in 24 hours if I'm not wrong (maybe more)...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a not-escaped regex. However you don't need `preg_replace`, just a `str_replace`

```
$email_content = str_replace( $link_pattern, $proposal_link, $email_content );
$email_content = str_replace( $link_pattern, $porposal_link_url, $email_content );
```

FYI, the right way for regex is, in this case:

```
$link_pattern = preg_quote('%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%');
$email_content = preg_replace( '/' . $link_pattern . '/', $proposal_link, $email_content);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with un-escaped regex. The `%` is not a meta character. `preg_quote('%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%') === '%%PROPOSAL_LINK%%';` in other words.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for the suggestion; i have tried both escaping the regex and as per your suggestion, using str_replace; still nothing happening however... btw is there any performance benefit in using str_replace ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know. For "unescaped" I mean "without a proper regex delimiter". But "unescaped" is more clear (even for a beginner) and is only one word. I added the `preg_quote` because if the OP (or someone else in future) use this code with another pattern with problematic chars, will have an error. Once `preg_quote` do not hurt, I just added it. @chrisguitarguy

Comment: @Ronnieinspain yes, str_replace is faster than preg_replace.

Comment: @Ronnieinspain have you tried to `var_dump($email_content)` and `var_dump($proposal_link)`?

Comment: just managed to fix it; for some reason the post_id wasn't coming through and adding global $post; fixed the whole thing.
Many thanks to G.M. and @chrisguitarguy.
Ill update the complete function above.